# Finding the common elements in 2 columns which is present in a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, recommendation-engine

[image of a data frame]

[image: 1]

I want to find the common elements which is present in top30 and played games column

i have used the below code , but it does not give me the right output

```
output : {f, 1, , ,, a, s, t, r, g, 2, ', y, o, e, [
```

The output which i am looking is

[image: 2]

```
Prediction1['precision_at_30'] = [
    set(a).intersection(b) for a, b in zip(Prediction1['played_games'], Prediction1['top 30'])]
```

Comment: https://github.com/ajayvd/stack-overflow  ( attaching the dataframe , since there was a mistake in screenshot ) --> i need to find the common games between top 30 and played games

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your columns seems to be the string representation of lists, so you can use `pd.eval` to convert your string in real python list before using `set` predicate:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'games': ["['abc', 'bef']", "['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']"], 
                   'played_games': ["['abc', 'bef', 'e']", "['b', 'f']"]})

df['result'] = df[['games', 'played_games']].apply(
    lambda x: set(pd.eval(x['games'])).intersection(pd.eval(x['played_games'])),
    axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                  games         played_games      result
0        ['abc', 'bef']  ['abc', 'bef', 'e']  {abc, bef}
1  ['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']           ['b', 'f']      {b, f}
```

**Update**: with your sample data

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajayvd/stack-overflow/main/testing.csv', index_col=0)

df['result'] = df[['top 30', 'played_games']].apply(
    lambda x: set(pd.eval(x['top 30'])).intersection(pd.eval(x['played_games'])),
    axis=1)

print(df['result'])

# Output:
0    {fdtsl, ashhof, ctiv, aeolus, batcat, drgch, a...
1                    {aogs, ashace, ashjut, bib, athn}
2                                               {aogs}
3                                     {ashjut, anwild}
4                                                   {}
Name: result, dtype: object
```

Comment: {o, c, ], i, , t, s, 1, j, f, ,, e, h, r, a,   -> thanks but i am getting output in this way which is wrong , and yes i have given the wrong screenshot its a list containing string

Comment: when i have used your code snipet i got the error stating "NumExpr 2 does not support Unicode as a dtype."

Comment: Update your post with the output of `Prediction2.head(5).to_dict('list')`

Comment: hi corralien , you can check my data frame.  https://github.com/ajayvd/stack-overflow  ( attaching the dataframe , since there was a mistake in screenshot )

Comment: thanks for your help  , its working fine now i have converted into a list of values  from ast import literal_eval
df = pd.read_csv('result.csv', converters={'top 30': literal_eval,'played_games':literal_eval})

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to check the `set` intersection:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda r: set(r['games']).intersection(r['played_games']), axis=1)
```

Example:

```
             games played_games      result
0  [abc, def, ghi]   [def, abc]  {abc, def}
```

Comment: I think the screenshot shows a string representation of lists because we can see single quotes. Try: `df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': ["['abc', 'def']", ['ghi', 'jkl']]})`

Comment: Yes I think you're right, in this case OP has your answer. One more example why providing images of data is bad practice.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right. Maybe one day, someone will write a tutorial **from notebook / excel to stackoverflow** :)

Comment: thanks for your responses  but i got the output in this way {o, c, ], i, , t, s, 1, j, f, ,, e, h, r, a,